# PHP Loop on website

Tags: php, magento, if-statement

I am trying to add an `if else` statement to a file in Magento.

Basically I want it to display different content depending on the body class.

For example, if the body element had a specific class, such as in:

```
<body class="specific-class">
```

Then within that body block, then the contents of it might display:

```
<section class="banner banner-inner <?php Mage::helper('function')->convert_category_name($category_name); ?>">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('breadcrumbs') ?>
        <?php echo $this->getLayout()->getBlock('breadcrumbs')->toHtml(); ?>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom-rip"></div>
</section>
```

But if the body had a different class, or no class at all, it would default to:

```
<div class="no_content">
    <?php echo="<h1>No content</h1>"; ?>
</div>
```

Does anyone know the syntax for performing such an operation?

Comment: What determines the body class? Where is the body class determined? When is the body class determined?  How is the body class determined?

Comment: PHP if: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php

PHP else: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.else.php

PHP for loop: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php

Keep in mind that if/else is not a loop.